# Batch script stops executing after `gulp` process is complete, does not continue executing the rest of the script

Tags: node.js, maven, batch-file, build, gulp

I am attempting to write a simple batch file to build a `gulp` project and a `maven` project.

The current file follows:

```
cd C:\my\file\path
cmd /k gulp maven-deploy-local
cd C:\my\file\path\two\project-pom-parent
cmd /k mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Whenever I run this script, the command line stops after line 2 and before line 3. I end up looking at this line in `cmd` with a blinking cursor:

> C:\my\file\path>

If I run the file without the `cmd /k` (as follows) then the prompt simply closes after line 2 and before line 3.

```
cd C:\my\file\path
gulp maven-deploy-local
cd C:\my\file\path\two\project-pom-parent
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

How can I modify the batch script so that it will continue and execute the commands on lines 3 and 4 and then remain open with the following line and blinking cursor?

> C:\my\file\path\two\project-pom-parent>

I am operating on **Windows 7 64-bit**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This task is specific enough to use this as well:

```
cd /d "C:\my\file\path"
cmd /c gulp maven-deploy-local
cd /d "C:\my\file\path\two\project-pom-parent"
cmd /k mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

In essence the first `cmd /k` can be changed to `cmd /c` so it executes the command and continues to the last command, which leaves the prompt open.

Comment: This solution is much easier to understand, use and maintain. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that does make sense Foxidrive.  The first CMD /C opens another environment so it returns to the original environment after it is done executing.  I can't remember why we came up with the logic I used which I remembered from a DosTips question.

Comment: @Squashman You're right - and if the user needed to use environment variables set in the gulp command then `cmd /c` wouldn't pass them back to the script.

Comment: @LanguidSquid Now that more discussion is here - is `gulp` a batch script or an executable?  If it's a batch script then you can use `call gulp maven-deploy-local` as Squashman implements, and if it's a command-line executable you can just use `gulp maven-deploy-local`

Comment: @foxidrive `gulp` is an executable for building compiled artifacts from code.

Comment: @LanguidSquid  So a normal command line executable would not need `cmd /c` or `call` - just use the gulp command line itself.

Answer (score 6):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%1"=="1" CMD /K ""%~f0" 1"
CD /d C:\my\file\path
CALL gulp maven-deploy-local
CD /d C:\my\file\path\two\project-pom-parent
CALL mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: This solution works, thanks. I'll upvote and accept the answer if you include an explanation of what the lines are doing so that I can use the tools represented here in the future :).

Comment: The CALL statements were needed to keep the batch file from closing after it executes each program.  The IF NOT statement is just a trick to execute the original batch file a 2nd time and keep it open by using the CMD /K.  So in theory it is executing your batch file twice.  The first time it just executes the IF NOT.  The second time the IF NOT is FALSE because I passed an argument to the batch file so it executes the last 4 lines of code instead.